# <Typescript> function parameter has generics. how to pass？

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript，encountered a problem
define

```js
    loadAnimation(params: AnimationConfigWithPath | AnimationConfigWithData): AnimationItem;

    export type AnimationConfigWithPath = AnimationConfig & {
        path?: string;
    }

    export type AnimationConfigWithData = AnimationConfig & {
        animationData?: any;
    }

    export type AnimationConfig<T extends 'svg' | 'canvas' | 'html' = 'svg'> = {
        container: Element;
        renderer?: T;
    }
```

my code

```js
lottie.loadAnimation({
            container: document.getElementById("test1")!, 
            renderer: 'canvas',  // Error: Type '"canvas"' is not assignable to type '"svg" | undefined'.
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            path: 'data.json'
        })
```

Error: Type '"canvas"' is not assignable to type '"svg" | undefined'.
I wonder how to write? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration

```
export type AnimationConfigWithPath = AnimationConfig & {
    path?: string;
}
```

does not pass a type parameter to `AnimationConfig`, which means the default value is used. So `renderer` will always be of type `'svg'`.

You can pass the generic parameter down to get what you are looking for.

```
function loadAnimation<T>(params: AnimationConfigWithPath<T> | AnimationConfigWithData<T>): AnimationItem { ... }

export type AnimationConfigWithPath<T extends 'svg' | 'canvas' | 'html'> = AnimationConfig<T> & {
    path?: string;
}

export type AnimationConfigWithData<T extends 'svg' | 'canvas' | 'html'> = AnimationConfig<T> & {
    animationData?: any;
}

export type AnimationConfig<T extends 'svg' | 'canvas' | 'html' = 'svg'> = {
    container: Element;
    renderer?: T;
}
```